# Load Standard library in .net core application

Tags: asp.net-core, mediatr

i have created one library using .net standard , am trying to use that in .net core api ,
but am getting error -

**Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples.**

inner exception -
**Could not load file or assembly 'RedisHelper.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.**

my mediatr injection as follow -

```
services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

my class DI -

```
 services.AddTransient<IRedisClient, RedisClient>();
```

can any one suggest me what i am missing here .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Error constructing handler for request of type
> MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[]. Register your handlers with the
> container. See the samples in GitHub for examples.
>
> inner exception - Could not load file or assembly 'RedisHelper.Client,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system
> cannot find the file specified.

As the exception message said, could not load the RedisHelper.Client assembly. Please check your .net core application and the .net standard library, where you add this assembly? Please ensure it adds success, you could also try to re-install it.

Besides, if you add the RedisHelper.Client assembly in the library, you should also add it in the .net core application.